# Multiple fonts in Font-Family property?

Tags: html

In the command

```
<span style="font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif">
   <font size="1">
       [Country]
   </font>
</span>
```

Why are there multiple fonts in the `font-family` property?

Does it mean that if the arial font is not installed so it will goto helvetica?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Yes.

> The font-family property can hold several font names as a "fallback" system. If the browser does not support the first font, it tries the next font.

From: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.asp

And as good practice:

> Start with the font you want, and always end with a generic family, to let the browser pick a similar font in the generic family, if no other fonts are available.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the font-family indicates the font priority.
If the browser does not support the first font, it tries the next font.
If the browser support arial, the style font will be arial. The browser use helvetica if does not support arial.
You can use the name of a font-family (times, courier, arial, ...) or the name of a generic-family (serif, sans-serif, cursive, "monospace", ...).