# How to set font family and size in html/css

Tags: html, css

I'd like to use css syntax in HTML document to set the font-family to "Arial" and font-size to 0.3cm for the whole document.

I use this code:

```
<style>
body { font-family: Arial; font-size: 0.3cm }
</style>
```

I am not sure if writing only Arial is enough, or should I write something like this?

```
<style>

body { font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 0.3cm }
  </style>
```

and I am also not sure if I cam use "cm" in the code, I mean it works in the browser but is it correct "code-wise" ?

thanks

Comment: It is best practice to use your second example, with several fonts, as fallbacks, just in case - even though Arial should always be available.

Comment: Dupe 1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297619/using-cm-mm-on-the-css-of-a-web-app-that-replicates-paper-interaction-is-a-good

Comment: thank you, and what about font size, any advice?

Comment: Dupe 2 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996632/multiple-fonts-in-font-family-property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> font-family: Arial

This means the browser will use Arial if you have it installed on your system. If not, it will use whatever the default font is for your browser.

> font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif

This means the browser will use Arial if you have it installed on your system. If not, it will use Helvetica Neue if you have it installed on your computer. If not, it will use Helvetica if you have it installed on your computer. If not, it will use whatever the default sans-serif font is for your browser.

Both are perfectly valid. They just do slightly different things.

> and I am also not sure if I cam use "cm" in the code

Yes, cm is a valid CSS unit of measurement.

Comment: I would note that cm is a unit best suited for print stylesheets, and there are better alternatives for screens.

Comment: not sure why you got downvoted. your answer is all correct, and there's no need to impose any opinions about what is the best use for the `cm` unit.

Comment: @MisterEpic in theory, I agree, though in reality, all of the units of measurement ultimately end up as virtual units.

Comment: I was not the downvoter, but my feeling is that given monitors use pixels as units of measurement, `px` would be a more appropriate for screen stylesheets, along with the other usual suspects (`em`, `rem`, etc..) I have no idea what 3 cm would be on some monitor where the size and pixel density are unknowns. The browser will still figure it out, but I think things would be more predictable with pixel-related units.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow The opinion is not mine: http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html

Comment: @MisterEpic, so you would recommend to use pixels instead of cm, in this case 11.338582677?

Comment: @Leonardo Absolutely use `cm` for physical media - e.g. in a print stylesheet for a piece of paper. If your stylesheet is to style a page for a browser, you should consider `px`, `em`, `rem`, `%`, etc... But note pixels are integers, round them off.

Comment: @MisterEpic but to be clear, and to quote the W3: `There is no restriction on which units can be used where`. The *intent* makes sense...use physical units for physical printing, virtual units for screens, but in reality, they all are interpreted the same by the browser. So it's more theory than reality.

Comment: @DA. While I understand that the browser will make a determination as to what the size will be, any physical unit of measurement is not recommended by the W3C for screens, though yes, it is perfectly legal. But if someone presented me a screen stylesheet with cms, inches and pts for sizes and dimensions, I would have a hard time trying to interpret it. If my header is 70 pts across, and my monitor is 24" with a pixel density of 250 ppi, how many pixels do I tell my designer to make her banner image? I'm sure people better at math could figure it out, but it would make kittens cry.

Comment: @MisterEpic I agree totally with you that 'cm' would just be hard to grok if I had to read through it for a screen CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure if writing only Arial is enough, or should I write something like this?

You can use Arial alone but It is advisable to use `font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;` Just is case **Arial** can not be used.

> and I am also not sure if I cam use "cm" in the code, I mean it works in the browser but is it correct "code-wise" ?

You can use **cm** but It seems it is recommended only for print by **w3.org**,check this link http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html

The recommended units for font size are **em, px, %,rem**

Comment: Note that the W3 is *not* w3schools.

Comment: @MisterEpic Yeah you are right and I've just added it but it doesn't support older versions of IE

Comment: True enough, that's why I don't support older versions of IE :)

Answer (score 1):

The [`font-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size) property can accept values of type [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Interpolation). As of the time of writing, the exhaustive list of these types (excluding experimental units) is:

> em, ex, ch, rem, vh, vw, vmin, vmax, px, mm, cm, in, pt, pc

So, yes. You can use `cm` (centimeters) as a unit for that property. You should be aware, though, that `1cm` rarely equals one true centimeter on screen, due to differing pixel densities on various displays. If that's *really* what you want, you could use the `mozmm` unit of measurement, although it is an experimental unit that is only supported by Firefox browsers. The `cm` unit is used more often in stylesheets targeted at physical printed media.

The [`font-family`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-family) property accepts a stack (comma-separated list) of font family names. The browser will use the first one in the stack that it happens to recognize (installed on the computer).

Using `font-family: Arial` is a *pretty* safe bet, since almost all computers have the Arial font, but to be safe it is best to include a couple of fall-back fonts. Quotation marks (or single-quotes) are traditionally used around multi-word font names or font names with numbers or symbols in them. It is also considered best-practice to include a `<generic-name>` at the end of the list. The exhaustive list of generic fonts is:

> serif, sans-serif, monospace, cursive, fantasy

So, the second option you listed for `font-family` is a little bit more "bulletproof". It lists some fall-back options and ends with a generic font in case the client has none of the hand-picked fonts installed.