# SendGrid Emails are Blank when Replying or Forwarding

Tags: email, sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

When forwarding our Campaign emails, we noticed that the email content that we received from SendGrid is blank when we forward or reply.

We've had multiple people look at this, and it happens in both Outlook and Gmail. The content itself is missing from all browsers when you are composing the Forward, and when you receive it.

Any idea what this is??
Thanks in advance!

Comment: We built our own email in HTML and CSS, and then uploaded it into the code editor. The emails look great when they arrive. They just vanish when replying or forwarding. Lol So odd!!

Answer (score 2):

We faced this issue when sending emails created by the Sendgrid Design Editor -- emails, when forwarded from Outlook, would appear empty.

To resolve this issue, we made a copy of the design and opened it with their code editor. Some of the code Sendgrid generates for the table cells (`<td>` tags) style attribute was the cause. Eliminating `visibility: hidden; opacity: 0;` from the style attribute `<td style="visibility: hidden; opacity: 0;">` solved the issue.

Below shows the exact changes made in our code to have emails appear normally when forwarded.

Before:

```
<td role="modules-container" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px; color:#000000; text-align:left;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="100%" align="left"><table class="module preheader preheader-hide" role="module" data-type="preheader" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="display: none !important; mso-hide: all; visibility: hidden; opacity: 0; color: transparent; height: 0; width: 0;">
```

After:

```
<td role="modules-container" style="padding:0px 0px 0px 0px; color:#000000; text-align:left;" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="100%" align="left"><table class="module preheader preheader-hide" role="module" data-type="preheader" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="display: none !important; mso-hide: all; color: transparent; height: 0; width: 0;">
```

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996632/multiple-fonts-in-font-family-property