# Font Awesome 5 Choosing the correct font-family in pseudo-elements

Tags: css, fonts, font-awesome, pseudo-element, font-awesome-5

I'm currently confused in using the icon in CSS pseudo-elements. There are 4 kind of font-family for fontawesome : `Font Awesome 5 Free`, `Font Awesome 5 Solid`, `Font Awesome 5 Brands`, `Font Awesome 5 Regular`

Here is the HTML :

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

### Case 1

I use this icon : https://fontawesome.com/icons/twitter?style=brands

As you can see, its a `brands` icon, so font-family : `Font Awesome 5 Brands`

```
h1:before {
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  content: "\f099"; /* TWITTER ICON */
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands";
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

IT WORKS!

### Case 2

I use this icon : https://fontawesome.com/icons/phone?style=solid

As you can see, its a `solid` icon, so font-family : `Font Awesome 5 Solid`

```
h1:before {
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  content: "\f095"; /* PHONE ICON */
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Solid";
  font-weight: 900;
}
```

DOESN'T WORK!

What did i do wrong?

How do we know when to use the correct font-family?

Comment: When in doubt, look at the fontawesome.css file for the `fa-phone` css class that came with your download.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simply use all of them in the same `font-family` and the browser will do the job. If it doesn't find it in the first one, it will use the second one. ([Multiple fonts in Font-Family property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996632/multiple-fonts-in-font-family-property))

By the way, the correct `font-family` is `Free` not `Solid` because the difference between *Solid* and *Regular* is the `font-weight` and both have the same `font-family`. **There is no** `Solid` and `Regular` in font-family, only `Free` and `Brands`.

You may also notice that almost all the `Solid` version of the icons are free BUT not all the `regular` version are free. Some of them are included in the PRO package. If an icon is not showing **it's not necessarely** a `font-family` issue.

*All the `Light` and `duotone` version are PRO ones.*

```css
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands","Font Awesome 5 Free";
}

.icon1:before {
  content: "\f099";
  /* TWITTER ICON */
  font-weight: 400;
}

.icon2:before {
  content: "\f095";
  /* PHONE ICON */
  font-weight: 900;
}

.icon3:before {
  content: "\f095";
  /* PHONE ICON */
  font-weight: 400;/*This one will not work because the regular version of the phone icon is in the Pro Package*/
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.11.0/css/all.css" >

<div class="icon1 icon"></div>
<div class="icon2 icon"></div>
<br>

<div class="icon3 icon"></div>
```

[image]

Reference: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements#define

---

Related question dealing with the `font-weight` issue: [Font Awesome 5 on pseudo elements shows square instead of icon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49754892/8620333)

Comment: you right.. especially in version 5 that `font-weight` is neccary so I think usink "Free" it is enough

Comment: @לבנימלכה it's not enough but mandatory ;) there is no `regular` or `solid` font-family ... there is only `Free` and `Brand`.

Comment: This only seems to work if you're loading via the Web Fonts & CSS method (`link` tag) as opposed to the SVG & JS framework (`script` tag).

Comment: @Todd with the JS version it will also work but you need to do more manipulation. Here is an example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48753688/fontawesome-replacement-on-li-tag-shows-empty-square/48753896#48753896

Comment: thank you
you just saved me :)

btw, fontawesome 5 team should know it