# Font Awesome 5 pseudo elements with Webpack

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I have been struggling with this for way too long and have no clue where I am going wrong.

I am trying to use fontawesome 5 in my webpack project. I have been able to use icons in HTML but if I try a pseudo selector it just returns the empty square. Read loads of articles and docs but nothing seems to work. Please help thanks.

```sh
npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

**index.js**

```js
    import 'bootstrap'
    import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.js'
    import '../scss/main.scss'

    window.FontAwesomeConfig = {
      searchPseudoElements: true
    }
```

**main.scss**

```css
    /// Bootstrap ///
    // -- Required
    @import "~bootstrap/scss/functions";
    @import "~bootstrap/scss/variables";
    @import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";

    // -- Optional
    @import "~bootstrap/scss/buttons";
    @import "~bootstrap/scss/code";
    @import "~bootstrap/scss/forms";
    @import "~bootstrap/scss/grid";
    @import "~bootstrap/scss/images";
    @import "~bootstrap/scss/modal";
    @import "~bootstrap/scss/reboot";
    @import "~bootstrap/scss/type";
    @import "~bootstrap/scss/transitions";
    @import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins/breakpoints";

    /// Modules ///
    @import 'modules/colors';
    @import 'modules/sizes';
    @import 'modules/fonts';
    @import 'modules/transitions';    

    /// Partial Files ///
    @import 'partials/jumbotron';

    /// Vendor Files ///
    @import 'vendor/reset';
```

**SCSS File _jumbotron.scss**

```css
    .products {
        background: $colour-red;

        .products-item {
          .products-item-header {
            .products-item-title {
              a {
                padding: $size-base;
                display: block;
                color: $colour-white;
                text-align: center;

                &:before {
                  font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands", "Font Awesome 5 Free";
                  display: block;
                  content: "\f095";
                  font-weight: 900;
                  font-size: 20px;
                  color: $colour-white;
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

**HTML**

```html
    <div class="products">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3 products-item">
                <div id="post-37">
                  <div class="products-item-header entry-header">
                    <h3 class="products-item-title entry-title">
                       <a href="http://localhost/wplocal/products/agribusiness">
                          Agribusiness
                        </a>
                    </h3>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

[image]

**Webpack Config**

```js
    const path = require('path')
    const webpack = require('webpack')
    const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
    const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
    const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
    // const devMode = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

    module.exports = {
        entry: { main: './src/js/index.js' },
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
            filename: 'js/[name].js'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                  use: {
                    loader:'babel-loader',
                    options: { presets: ['es2015'] }
                  },
                  test: /\.js$/,
                  exclude: /node_modules/
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
                    use: [
                        'style-loader',
                        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                        'css-loader',
                        'sass-loader'
                    ]
                },
                {
                  test: /\.(gif|png|jp(e*)g|svg)$/,
                  use: [{
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: {
                      limit: 1000000, //Convert images < 1mb to base 64 strings
                      name: 'images/[name].[ext]'
                    }
                  }] 
                },
                {
                  test: /.(ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
                  use: [{
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                      name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]',
                      publicPath: '../'
                    }
                  }]
                }
            ]
        },
        devServer: {
            contentBase: "./dist"
        },
        plugins: [
            new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
                inject: false,
                hash: true,
                template: './src/index.html',
                filename: 'index.html'
            }),
            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: 'css/style.css',
                chunkFilename: 'css/style.css'
            }),
            new CopyWebpackPlugin ([
              {
                from: './src/images',
                to: 'images'
              }
            ]),
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
              $: 'jquery',
              jQuery: 'jquery',
              'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
              Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
            })
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FontAwesome - Choosing the correct font-family in CSS pseudo-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50680160/fontawesome-choosing-the-correct-font-family-in-css-pseudo-elements)

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49754892/font-awesome-shows-square-instead-of-icon-when-used-directly-in-css/49755090#49755090

Comment: I figured so too but I tried everything in the above threads to no success

Comment: If your using the js version do you still need to include css file?

Comment: no need the CSS with JS, can you share a full working code so we can debug?

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
  font-family: 'Font Awesome\ 5 Free';
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment but no luck unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Set `searchPseudoElements` to `true` in the fontawesome-svg-core config object.
And verify if the font-family and content properties have the correct values.

Taken from the fontawesome docs:

https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/javascript-api/setup/configuration

> By enabling searchPseudoElements to true (it’s false by default) you
> can have Font Awesome search your DOM for any elements that have:

> A Font Awesome matching font-family,

> A content property

> Valid font-family values are: Font Awesome 5 Solid, Font Awesome 5 Regular, Font Awesome > 5 Light, and Font Awesome 5 Brands.

**Example**

```js
import {library, dom, config} from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import {faCheck} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faCheck";

config.searchPseudoElements = true; //<----- config

export default () => {

    library.add(faCheck);
    dom.watch();

}
```

**Example:**

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.1/js/all.js" data-search-pseudo-elements></script>
  <style>
  .glasses::before {
    display: none;
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Solid';
    content: "\f530";
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <span class="glasses"></span>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<style>
.element:before {
content: "\f000";
font-family: FontAwesome;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
text-decoration: inherit;
color: #000;
font-size: 18px;
padding-right: 0.5em;
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
left: 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.