# I can't get my font-awesome icons to show up. Tried importing css with multiple methods

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, font-awesome-5

I'm building a website portfolio using a HTML template. I don't have too much experience with css, but after importing the font-awesome css file both as a link and file in my django project, the icons are showing up as little boxes. I know the css file is being recognized because when I comment it out the boxes go away. I think there may be something deeper going on with the css that I don't understand.

I suspect there's something going on in the main css file if someone could help me out. Thanks!

Here's the code from the template:

```
<ul class="special">
    <li><i class="fab fa-pencil" title="Edit"></i></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-search"><span class="label">Magnifier</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-tablet"><span class="label">Tablet</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-flask"><span class="label">Flask</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="icon fa-cog"><span class="label">Cog?</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Here's what I've imported:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="{% static "css/main.css" %}" />
 <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/all.css" %}" > -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
```

Comment: Are your font-awesome font files (woff, ttf) in the same directory as the CSS? Also you could try replacing e.g. `class="icon fa-search"` with `class="icon fa fa-search"`

Comment: Open your console and look for any red lines letting you know about the missing font files. `all.css` assumes the font files are there, with the same relative path as in what you downloaded from fontawesome website.

Comment: Yes, they are in the same directory. Tried those modifications to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `fas` class and the pencil one will not show because it belong to the PRO package<sup>**1**</sup> (https://fontawesome.com/icons/pencil?style=solid)

```css
ul a {
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size:25px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">
<ul class="special">
  <li><i class="fas fa-pencil" title="Edit"></i></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="fas fa-search"><span class="label">Magnifier</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="fas fa-tablet"><span class="label">Tablet</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="fas fa-flask"><span class="label">Flask</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="fas fa-cog"><span class="label">Cog?</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

You cannot use the regular version of these icons `far` because all of them belong to the PRO package<sup>**2**</sup> so they won't show

```css
ul a {
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size:25px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.0/css/all.css">
<ul class="special">
  <li><i class="far fa-pencil" title="Edit"></i></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="far fa-search"><span class="label">Magnifier</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="far fa-tablet"><span class="label">Tablet</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="far fa-flask"><span class="label">Flask</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="far fa-cog"><span class="label">Cog?</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

https://fontawesome.com/icons/tablet?style=regular

https://fontawesome.com/icons/search?style=regular

https://fontawesome.com/icons/flask?style=regular

https://fontawesome.com/icons/cog?style=regular

---

**1** As you can see below, all the versions of this icon are PRO so there is no way to use this icon with the Free package:

[image]

**2** As you can see below, only the solid version isn't  PRO so only this one is included in the Free package unlike the 2 others.

[image]

Related questions:

[Font Awesome 5 on pseudo elements shows square instead of icon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49754892/8620333)

[Font Awesome 5 Choosing the correct font-family in pseudo-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50680160/8620333)

Comment: Thanks! That seemed to do the trick to get them appear. Two of them have bizarre black lines running through them that disappear when the .js animation is activated... Any ideas what that is?

Comment: @KennyWorkman probably there is more CSS involved? can you create a fiddle with all your code?

Answer (score 0):

Put it on top of all css and try to use without integrity and crossorigin parameters  because even a little change by devs on file may not match with integrity and crossorigin you have on your website so it won't be used.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the fontawesome files in your local directory (asset/fontawesome)
Then Load fontawesome with static

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/font-awesome.min.css'%}">
```

You can check this github repo [here](https://github.com/beedyboy/clearance/blob/master/templates/base_layout.html)