# font awesome scss unicode showing rectangle

Tags: css, npm, sass, font-awesome

I have installed font awesome with npm like this:

```
npm install @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

I have added this in my scss file:

```
$fa-font-path: '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts';
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome";
```

This is how I am trying to set an icon:

```
i:before {
    content: "\f303";
    font-weight: 900;
    font-family: $fa-font-path;
}
```

But I am seeing just a rectangle instead of the actual icon.

Comment: a path is not a valid value for font-family

Comment: @TemaniAfif What is a valid value then?

Comment: read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49690376/8620333 and this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62239254/8620333

Comment: @TemaniAfif I did actually, before making this question. I've tried all the suggested but it doesn't work unfortunately