How are fonts substituted in CSS font-family
Recently, I've stumbled upon a code like this:
span { font-family: Helvetica, 'Segoe UI'; }

<span>Lorem ipsum</span>

I don't have Helvetica on my computer but Segoe UI is present, so the expected outcome is that the text will be rendered using Segoe. However, Arial is used (as verified in the DevTools).
After some playing, I'm sure that my browser treats Helvetica entry as if it was Arial, so the font-picking process stops there – at an unexisting font.
How is it decided? Are there any font substitution lists? I can't find anything like this in the CSS Fonts Module spec.
It happens both in Chromium Edge and Firefox, on Windows 11.

This might be https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-insider-program/wrong-fonts-in-multiple-browsers/m-p/3637533

please check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996632/multiple-fonts-in-font-family-property, https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-family.php

@JeffZeitlin, Thanks! It seems to be exactly the cause of treating Helvetica as Arial

No need to experiment: open your Firefox dev tools, and just look at what font the browser knows it applied (not as CSS property, but as actual rendering. There's a dedicated font tab, and hovering over fonts will highlight all text that uses that font on the page. Incredibly valuable dev tools panel)

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, I wasn't asking what font is applied but rather why certain font is applied

"After some playing, I'm sure that my browser treats Helvetica entry as if it was Arial" says there is guess work involved, so take the guess work out of debugging. I wasn't trying to answer your post (you already have an answer), but pointing out to not just you, but all future visitors who find this post, that there is a way to simply check.

Yes, I wanted to make sure that Arial is applied in place of Helvetica and not because it could be a default sans serif font.

Based on your reply to my comment on the question, you have some font substitution entries in the registry, and one of them is to substitute Arial for any request for Helvetica. This is described in this posting on Microsoft's Tech Community; essentially, there are entries in the registry under HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes to cause applications to use fonts that you do have when certain putatively similar fonts that you do not have are requested.
